# What is the Best way to Show 50,000 markers on Google map api

Tags: google-maps-markers

The usual way of adding a new instance take a lot of time. Please help me solve this

```
for (var element in results) {
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: results[element],
    title: element
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
    window.open('msg', '', 'configs')
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use geojson format for displaying markers.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer#maps_layer_data_simple-javascript